# HTML get user input to span

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the user input into the span. When I change

```
var word = document.getElementById('span_key').innerHTML; --> var word = document.getElementById('input_search').value;
```

it works fine, but i can't do it like that, because the other things in the future
wouldn't work.
Please don't make it duplicate,I'm searching now for day's.
Thank you!

```
        <div class="tag">
          <span id="span_key" value=""></span>
          <i class="material-icons">close</i>
        </div>
        <input id="input_search" value="" />
      </div>

      <button type="button" id="bt" onclick="clicked();">Click Me!</button>
      
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function clicked(){
        var word = document.getElementById('span_key').innerHTML;
        alert(word);
              window.open('https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/'+word);
        }
      </script>
```

Comment: `<span id="span_key" value=""></span>` Span HTML element does not have value attribute.  And it is not clear what are trying to achieve as your span content is empty, same as your value attribute.

Comment: Your question is not clear about your the issue you are getting

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the user input betweet <span>Here</span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define handler for `keyup` event to get the value of `input` when the `enter` key is pressed.

On that handler, you can assign `input` value to `span` as follows.

```js
function clicked() {
  var word = document.getElementById('span_key').innerHTML;
  alert(word);
  //window.open('https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/' + word);
}

function inputKeyUp(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    // Enter is pressed
    document.getElementById("span_key").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input_search").value;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tag">
  <span id="span_key" value=""></span>
  <i class="material-icons">close</i>
</div>
<input id="input_search" value="" onkeyup="inputKeyUp(event)" />
<button type="button" id="bt" onclick="clicked();">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`value` is not the default attribute of the `span` tag.

So to get the value of `value` attribute, you need to use `getAttribute` function.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("span_key").getAttribute("value"));
```

```html
<span id="span_key" value="Test Value"></span>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the user input betweet <span>Here</span>

Comment: Then it's not clear. Can you explain what you really need?

Comment: Okay. The user tips something into the input. The user presses Enter and it goes into the span. And then i want to get the word, that is between <span></span>.

Comment: I have attached another answer.